# Use own number to send SMS in Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have had a couple of customers wondering if they can use their own phone numbers to send out SMS using Twilio.

I am wondering if this is possible?

What are the carrier charges in this case and do I need to verify this number before enabling this functionality for an individual user?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it should be addressed to Twilio support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number you want to send messages from (or to) needs to be controlled by Twilio. However, it is possible to port your number from your current provider over to Twilio and thus give Twilio control over that number. This is possible, at least in some countries.

This [support article here](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179348-Porting-a-Phone-Number-to-Twilio) describes how this can be done for US numbers.

Comment: It's also possible to [host SMS for landline numbers](https://www.twilio.com/docs/phone-numbers/hosted-numbers) if that is of use to your customers